# Algorithm to solve monetary obligation

Tags: algorithms

i Need some help to find an algorithm for the following Problem.

A Group of n persons lend each other some Money. A -> B, B -> C, C -> A, and so on. Now i want to find out how much Money each Person has to return to who and eliminate unecessary transactions loke in the 2nd example below.

Some examples:

- For 2 ist easy. A -> B 10, and B -> A 5 gives A -> B 5
- A -> B 10, B -> C 10, gives A -> C 10

Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm sure this is a standard problem in Graph theory. But if it is, I don't remember it. You have a directed Graph of edge values and you're looking for a spanning tree.

Comment: The first step in solving this is to find out how it is solved on paper. I think this is a question more for a site about algorithms than for Mathematica. Once you know what algorithm to use, you can ask about using Mathematica to implement it.

Comment: So the algorithm I would first think up of is this. 1. Find a spanning tree. 2. Pick an edge not in the spanning tree. Modify the values of the edges along the spanning tree connecting those two values so that the edge may be removed. 3. Repeat (2) until all edges are removed.

Comment: Do you need to do this in a way that guarantees that minimal amounts of money are transferred? That might not be feasible. I'm not sure. But it might be feasible to use a heuristic of some kind in selecting the spanning tree.

Comment: At any rate, programming this isn't a easy, but also not that hard for an experienced programmer. Are you familiar with graph theory? You may want to try implementing this or trying it out on small example graphs first.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this becomes $NP$ when you ask for an optimal algorithm

Comment: Thank you for all the good suggestions. Finding an algorithm is of course the best way but i have difficulties to find one because i have no idea how to name this Problem. Maybe anyone has an idea how it is called ? And yes i want to implement it on my own just to learn something (i am a programmer) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Setup a variable (a bank account, so to speak) $s_X$for each person $X$. For each instance of "$X$ lends amount $Y$ to $Z$" increase variable $s_X$ by $Y$ and decrease variable $s_Z$ by $Y$. In the end each variable tells how much money in total they should obtain back (or should give back in case of negative amounts). Observe that the sum of all accounts is zero at any point in time.

You can now resolve the debts in (at least) two ways:

- Everybody with a negative account $s_X<ß$ puts the corresponding positive amount $|s_X|$ into a central "pool". After that everybody with positive account $s_X>0$ takes from the pool the amount $s_X$ they are entitled to.
- To avoid a pool: As long as somebody has a non-zero account, there must be someone with positive and someone with negative account. Say, we have $s_X>0$ and $s_Y<0$. Then $a=\min\{s_X,-s_Y\}>0$. Now let $Y$ give $a$ to $X$, and as above replace $s_Y$ with $s_Y+a$, $s_X$ with $s_X-a$. At least one of $s_X,s_Y$ becomes zero by this. Hence after at most $n$ such steps everything is balanced out (in fact at most $n-1$ as the last step will zero two accounts).